# Does the matrix equation $XA = XB$ always have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $A,B$ be two $n \times m$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$. Is it possible to always find a $m \times n$ matrix $X$ such that

$$XA = XB$$

Comment: Yes: the $0$ $m\times n$ matrix.

Comment: If $n=m=1$, is it possible to always find $x$ such that $ax=bx$ for any $a,b$? If $a\neq b$, the only $x$ possible is 0. So, in the $m\times n$ case, the $X=0$ matrix is always a solution of what you want. But if you want a non-trivial solution, you will need to impose additional conditions on $A,B,m,n$.

Comment: $X=0$ may be the only choice, for $B=0$ and certain $A\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$XA=XB\to X(A-B)=0$$

So, you must have $X_{m\times n}$ matrix where the line space is orthogonal to the column space of $A-B$.

The line space of $X$ is inside $\Bbb R^n$, and we have $m$ vectors in it. The same is true for the column space of $A-B$.

So we have that $\dim[\text{column space } (A-B)]\le m$.

So it is only possible to find such line space if we have

$$n-\dim[\text{column space } (A-B)]\ge m$$

If that happen we can find a set of $m$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ such that  it is orthogonal to the column space of $A-B$.

Comment: thank you. Another related question: Does the equation AX=B always have a unique solution? I assume the matrices to have entries over the real numbers.

Comment: $A,X,B$ are the same like before? If so, it doesn't make sense because $(AX)_{n\times n}$ and $B_{n\times m}$

Comment: Assume $A$ to be $X_{m \times n}$ and $B$ to be a new arbitrary matrix. Also, in your answer above, I won't get a zero entry in the matrix if i multiply the row $i$ in $X_{m \times n}$ with the column $i+1$ of $A-B$, am I missing something?

Comment: @conrad: you are right, it is incomplete. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @conrad: I think it is better now.

Comment: @conrad: Is it clear?